# Third party JAR's in java

Tags: java

I included the 3rd party jar file in the java project but still this is showing compile time error.
 I included the path of the jar file in add external jar's in java.

```
package com.aamir;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;//compile time error occurs here.

public class ReadCSV3 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    CSVReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        //Get the CSVReader instance with specifying the delimiter to be used
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("SampleCSVFile.csv"),',');
        String [] nextLine;
        //Read one line at a time
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)
        {
            for(String token : nextLine)
            {
                //Print all tokens
                System.out.println(token);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly does the stacktrace state the problem is ?

Comment: Never say "there's an error" without saying *what the error is*.

Comment: What's the error? Can you post the **exact** error please?

Comment: @stultuske,CSVReader cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: its not including the au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader in the program

Comment: Your classpath setting is probably not correct.

Comment: @NilsH, can u plz elaborate.

Comment: @Nilsh, do i need to provide this jar file in classpath or simply by clicking and going to properties option in project file inside eclipse

Comment: Many packages come in two Jars - one for the actual classes, and the other for the Javadoc. Please make sure that the JAR you added to the project is the actual jar containing the class files, not the Javadoc jar, which has the same hierarchy but no class files.

Comment: @Zawinski please update your post with the **full stacktrace** or the **full error message**. This commenting thing won't help neither you nor us. Also, what's the name of the **exact** JAR that you've imported/included in your classpath?

Comment: @Buhake, here `import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;` it is showing red line and error message is `The import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;` cannot be resolved

Comment: What JAR is this class found?

Comment: Which JAR can you find the class that you've mentioned? What's the **exact** name of the JAR?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi, opencsv-2.2-sources

Comment: That's the problem right there. You have the **sources only** (uncompiled source) JAR file and not the **binary** JAR (it **must** contain the `.class` files). You need `opencsv-2.2.jar` instead.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi, but on right clicking it it shows `Type of File : WinRAR archive(.jar)

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can build a source only JAR. You need a binary JAR.

Comment: @Bukahe, thatz what I am asking for, how to do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are including the **source only** JAR file. That's the problem right there. You have the **sources only** (uncompiled source) JAR file and not the **binary** JAR (it **must** contain the `.class` files). You need `opencsv-2.2.jar` instead.

Here is a [zip](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/opencsv/opencsv-2.2.jar.zip) file of the binary JAR.

Comment: I think you are right ,so can u plz provide me the link where can I get the binary JAR.

Comment: See my updated post. Hopefully you will know how to do a Google Search next time.

Answer (score 0):

> I included the path of the jar file in add external jar's in java.

You need to add it to the project.
You didn't mention exactly how to added the jar. Can you please post the screenshot of

`Right click project` --> `Build Path` --> `Configure` --> `Libararis (3rd Tab )` --> `Add External Jar`

You should add the jar here. Please do so if not already done.

Comment: I already did the exact same thing , and still its showing error.

Comment: Then try to a `clean build` from `Project` menu.

Comment: Open the jar you added. Check it indeed has all the contents. Might be the jar is corrupt.

Comment: yes it contains `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader` and META-INF folder.

Answer (score 0):

What development tools are you using? Are you compiling at the command line or in an IDE?

If at the command line, you need to include the third party JAR in the CLASSPATH - either as an environment variable or as an argument to javac.

If in an IDE such as Eclipse, you need to specify the add the JAR to the build path in the project.

Firstly, just for sanity's sake, double-check that the JAR is in the build path - that you have given it the right name and the right path - you should see it in the Referenced Libraries section of your Java project if you expand it in the Project View. Try removing it and adding it again.

Then, secondly, check that the class you are importing exists - that you have got the right package name and class name (it is case sensitive). You should be able to expand the JAR in Eclipse and see the packages and classes inside it.

Thirdly, if you are certain that everything is correct, try to use Eclipse's auto-import feature - delete your import line and press CTRL-SHIFT-O (for Organise Imports) and see if it imports the right class.

If it is not auto-importing, then it indicates that the class is not in the class path. Try steps 1 and 2 again.

Also, try cleaning `Project` --> `Clean` --> `Clean all projects`

Comment: I am using eclipse and yes i included it in the build path but still it is showing error.

Comment: yes I unzipped the jar file bundle and it contains yes it contains `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader` and META-INF folder.

Comment: and on using aut-import feature its not showing this import.